# What is causing elasticsearch to shutdown shortly after starting up?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I'm having an issue with Elasticsearch on EC2 where I'm starting up several new instances from the same AMI, and very occasionally (like < 1% of the time), the Elasticsearch service will stop shortly after starting. I've looked at the log file, but it's not really clear to me why the service is stopping. Are there any clues in this that I'm missing, or is there anywhere else I should look for logs when this happens?

```
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,251][INFO ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [ip-10-0-0-68] no discovery configuration found, will perform best-effort cluster bootstrapping after [3s] unless existing master is discovered
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,375][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [ip-10-0-0-68] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{ip-10-0-0-68}{C1lEYCg6RUWry4avn4isxw}{IjXE3KNOQO2UeZyrX2o3FA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=32601837568, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 4, version: 26, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{ip-10-0-0-68}{C1lEYCg6RUWry4avn4isxw}{IjXE3KNOQO2UeZyrX2o3FA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=32601837568, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,416][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [ip-10-0-0-68] master node changed {previous [], current [{ip-10-0-0-68}{C1lEYCg6RUWry4avn4isxw}{IjXE3KNOQO2UeZyrX2o3FA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=32601837568, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}, term: 4, version: 26, reason: Publication{term=4, version=26}
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,446][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [ip-10-0-0-68] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,447][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-0-68] started
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,595][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [ip-10-0-0-68] license [a9a29e21-5167-497e-9e49-ccc785ea2d47] mode [basic] - valid
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,596][INFO ][o.e.x.s.s.SecurityStatusChangeListener] [ip-10-0-0-68] Active license is now [BASIC]; Security is disabled
[2020-07-28T18:17:44,602][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [ip-10-0-0-68] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2020-07-28T18:18:29,947][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-0-68] stopping ...
[2020-07-28T18:18:29,962][INFO ][o.e.x.w.WatcherService   ] [ip-10-0-0-68] stopping watch service, reason [shutdown initiated]
[2020-07-28T18:18:29,963][INFO ][o.e.x.w.WatcherLifeCycleService] [ip-10-0-0-68] watcher has stopped and shutdown
[2020-07-28T18:18:30,014][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [ip-10-0-0-68] [controller/2184] [Main.cc@150] Ml controller exiting
[2020-07-28T18:18:30,015][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [ip-10-0-0-68] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
[2020-07-28T18:18:30,024][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-0-68] stopped
[2020-07-28T18:18:30,024][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-0-68] closing ...
[2020-07-28T18:18:30,032][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-0-68] closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[2020-07-28T18:18:29,947][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-0-68] stopping ...
```

This log line means Elasticsearch shut down gracefully after receiving a shutdown signal (typically `SIGTERM`) from an external source. It's not possible to say what the external source is, it depends on your system. It could for instance be `systemd` if that's how you're starting Elasticsearch. If so, hopefully its logs tell you why it's sending that shutdown signal.